# How to setting to draw a line connect the stack bar

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to draw a chart like this
[stack bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1ruL.png)

but i don't know how to setting config to display a line connect between the bars as shown above. 
This is my demo code:

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
      chart: {
        type: 'bar'
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['今週', '前週']
      },
      legend: {
        enabled: false
      },
      yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
          text: null
        },
        lineWidth: 1,
        gridLineDashStyle: 'Dot',
        plotLines: [{
          width: 1,
          value: 100,
        }]
      },
      plotOptions: {
        bar: {
          stacking: 'percent',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{y} %'
          }
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Ad Group 1',
        data: [20, 18]
      }, {
        name: 'Ad Group 2',
        data: [19, 18]
      }, {
        name: 'Ad Group 3',
        data: [16, 38]
      }, {
        name: 'Ad Group 4',
        data: [35, 22]
      }],
      exporting: {
        enabled: false
      }
    });
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vinhlv2788/emta9p8k/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve something like in the picture by adding additional line series with proper data which you can get from the points object, below is the demo which should clarify what I had in mind.

```
events: {
  load(){
    let chart = this;

    chart.series.forEach((s,i) => {
        if(i !== 0){
        chart.addSeries({
            type: 'line',
            data: [{x: 0.24, y: s.points[0].stackY}, {x: 0.76, y: s.points[1].stackY}],
          color: 'red',
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          },
          enableMouseTracking: false,
        })
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5Lej2arw/1/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries

If something is unclear or you have any additional questions - feel free to ask!

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.